# How to place logo in center of a background image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to place the logo in center of a background image.I tried this by adding margin.But when i resize the screen in small size it is creating extra space.I think this is not the right way.Please help me to solve this problem.
[image: problem]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="details-section section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="equal row">
                <div class="big-small">
                    <div class="big col-sm-8">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Vintage bike" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small col-sm-4"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="small-big"></div>
                <div class="big-small-big"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.details-section .big {
    background: url("images/vintage-bike.jpg") no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
}
.details-section .big img {
    width: 92px;
    margin: 180px auto;
}
```

here i am updating the working fiddle of this code.

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zhccdbz7/1/)

Comment: your full code brother?  something is missing in your code.

Comment: can you create a demo, that will be easy for others to help you?

Comment: Not full code....Just the main part... @Fiido

Comment: Is the background image supposed to become full-width at under 768px or stay as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First version:

```
.details-section .big{
    position: relative;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.details-section .big img{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Second version, it works with only fixed container height, but sometime useful:

```
.details-section .big{
    height: 150px; // Change if need
    background: #f5f5f5;
    text-align: center;
}
.details-section .big:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.details-section .big img{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7o8bndtv/

Comment: If you set a background image it is getting cut.And Background image will not remain responsive if you fix height and width. But thanks at least i am getting close to solution.

Comment: You don't need to fix width in both version and height in first. So it's not affect on responsibility, setup container first.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the Class text-center in the div containing img and make the image verticla align center in the div

```
<div class="big col-sm-8 text-center myclass">
   <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Vintage bike" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myclass {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: It will not work.Text center will place the logo in center of horizontal.Not vertically.

Comment: remove margin: 180px auto; from your css

Comment: I did it.And placed text center class.It is not working.

Comment: do you have added the myclass also ?

Comment: i have not the running environment

Comment: i am just suggesting the hints for doing the job